# send fileupload to WCF

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, wcf

I have fileupload and some input text,I want to use WCF to update values to DB.

so far I send all input values via string array,but I can't see how to upload the file to the server using the WCF

html:

```
 <input id="file" type="file" >
   <textarea name="textarea" class="jqte"> </textarea>
...
```

javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "/WebServices/forum.svc/InsertMessage",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ currentMessage: currentMessage }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
```

WCF:

```
  [OperationContract]
        public void InsertMessage(List<string> currentMessage)
        {

            return;
        }
```

any idea how to slove this issue?

Thanks

Baaroz

Comment: use uplick.js...it makes your task super simple..i did the same mistake of sending a file by ajax..and i failed...use an iframe or some js..that might help..just google js for file upload..there are tons of js available..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same thing recently and failed.

Its best to use a js in such case.http://www.enfew.com/12-excellent-ajax-upload-plugins/

Many of them uses ajax if you are on a modern browser or falls back to an iFrame for old browsers. So browser compatibility is also not an issue.

I myself used https://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/ 
.Its pretty simple to use and does what you need.

Comment: uplick.js is good option ,but can I start it on Upon request?like button click ,instead of the browse button?

Comment: yes,you can ..on click of href,button div..watever you want...just give your element an id of uploader...i did it on a href..

Comment: thanks VAGABOND,but I want to upload the file on Demand ,if I give the id of the button ,it open the file browser.I want to let the user complete all the fields on the page and just then, to send the file to the server.

Comment: then validate it accordingly...for example..if contact and name field are filed only the...allow the user to upload file...there is an onstart function given in upclick..

Comment: thanks,last question please:) can I Limit file size and file type?